# Faltando algumas keywords para Visual Basic

Tags: bug, tag-específica, syntax-highlighting

Está faltando as seguintes keywords para serem colorizadas na linguagem Visual Basic .NET: 
<kbd>`NameOf`</kbd> <kbd>`Strict`</kbd> <kbd>`Compare`</kbd> <kbd>`Infer`</kbd> <kbd>`Using`</kbd> <kbd>`From`</kbd>

Poderia ser colorizado essas keywords?